# Concat a list of pandas data frames with a mixture of the same and different column names

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

**I have a list of data frames that I want to merge into one data frame**.

Data frames my the list that have the same column names have different indexes and vice versa. Each data frame has 1 row, and 80 columns and the list has a total length of 8,000 data frames.

Here is a scaled down example of my list of data frames:

```
import pandas as pd

u = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2, '111']], columns = ['a', 'b', 'id'])
u = u.set_index('id')

v = pd.DataFrame(data=[[3, 4, '222']], columns = ['a', 'b', 'id'])
v = v.set_index('id')

w = pd.DataFrame(data=[[5, 6, '333']], columns = ['a', 'b', 'id'])
w = w.set_index('id')

x = pd.DataFrame(data=[[7, 8, '444']], columns = ['a', 'b', 'id'])
x = x.set_index('id')

y = pd.DataFrame(data=[[9, 10, '111']], columns = ['c', 'd', 'id'])
y = y.set_index('id')

z = pd.DataFrame(data=[[11, 12, '222']], columns = ['c', 'd', 'id'])
z = z.set_index('id')

list_df = [u, v, w, x, y, z]
```

**How can I create a single merged table that looks like:**

```
id    a     b    c    d
--------------------------
111   1.0   2.0  9.0  10.0
222   3.0   4.0  11.0 12.0
333   5.0   6.0  NaN  NaN
444   7.0   8.0  NaN  NaN
```

At present, due to the size of my list, I have been using `pd.concat`. However, `pd.concat(list_df, axis = 0)` gives:

```
id    a     b    c    d
--------------------------
111   1.0   2.0  NaN  NaN
222   3.0   4.0  NaN  NaN
333   5.0   6.0  NaN  NaN
444   7.0   8.0  NaN  NaN
111   NaN   NaN  9.0  10.0
222   NaN   NaN  11.0 12.0
```

and `pd.concat(list_df, axis = 1)` gives:

```
id    a    b    a    b    a    b    a    b    c    d    c    d
----------------------------------------------------------------
111   1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  9.0  10.0 NaN  NaN
222   NaN  NaN  3.0  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  11.0 12.0
333   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0  6.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN 
444   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  7.0  8.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
pd.concat([u, v, w, x, y, z], sort=False).set_index('id').groupby(level=0).first()
```

Yields:

```
       a    b     c     d
id                       
111  1.0  2.0   9.0  10.0
222  3.0  4.0  11.0  12.0
333  5.0  6.0   NaN   NaN
444  7.0  8.0   NaN   NaN
```

Note, you do not need to `set_index()` separately for each dataframe.

**Explanation:**

You can pass a list of dataframes to `pd.concat()` with keyword `sort=False`, which is new in pandas version 0.23.0, as the previous behavior was to sort by default IIUC (see docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html)). You can then use `set_index('id')` to set the index of the concatenated dataframe. Finally, you can `groupby(level=0)` to group the dataframe by it's level 0 index (`'id'`) and take the first non-NaN value for each row via `first()`.

Comment: Sweet solution. A little explanation would be great to learn something new. Also, I got this error while executing `concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort'`

Comment: For older versions of pandas, just remove sort keyword.

Comment: Added an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping dfs with same columns together and then apply outer join

```
import pandas as pd

u = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2, '111']], columns = ['a', 'b', 'id'])
u = u.set_index('id')

v = pd.DataFrame(data=[[3, 4, '222']], columns = ['a', 'b', 'id'])
v = v.set_index('id')

w = pd.DataFrame(data=[[5, 6, '333']], columns = ['a', 'b', 'id'])
w = w.set_index('id')

x = pd.DataFrame(data=[[7, 8, '444']], columns = ['a', 'b', 'id'])
x = x.set_index('id')

y = pd.DataFrame(data=[[9, 10, '111']], columns = ['c', 'd', 'id'])
y = y.set_index('id')

z = pd.DataFrame(data=[[11, 12, '222']], columns = ['c', 'd', 'id'])
z = z.set_index('id')

list_df = [u, v, w, x]
df=pd.concat(list_df, axis = 0)
df2=pd.concat([y,z], axis = 0)
df.join(df2, how='outer')
```

Output

```
    a   b   c       d
id              
111 1   2   9.0     10.0
222 3   4   11.0    12.0
333 5   6   NaN     NaN
444 7   8   NaN      NaN
```